# Redux Thunk Action = Undefined in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch a function from componentWillMount.  The bound action creator function fetchDraftAdventures works outside of componentWillMount but not inside.

```
componentWillMount() {
    let {draftAdventures, editableAdventures} = this.props;
    console.log("this props")
    this.props.fetchDraftAdventures(1);
    console.log(' adventures props', this.props)
  }
```

App connected

```
export default withRouter(connect(
  state => {
    return {
      editableAdventures: state.editableAdventures,
      draftAdventures: state.draftAdventures,
    };
  },
  dispatch => ({
    fetchAdventureEditable: bindActionCreators(fetchAdventureEditable, dispatch),
    fetchEditableAdventures: bindActionCreators(fetchEditableAdventures, dispatch),
    fetchAdventureDraft: bindActionCreators(fetchAdventureDraft, dispatch),
    fetchDraftAdventures: bindActionCreators(fetchDraftAdventures, dispatch),
    dispatch
  })
)(AdventuresDashboard));
```

Here's the action itself:

```
// Constants
import {
  GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REQUESTED,
    GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_SUCCEEDED,
    GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REJECTED
} from '../../../constants/Actions'

import {get} from '../../../lib/request';

const DraftAdventures = (args) => {
  console.log('draft adventures', args)
  const Authorization = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

  const pageNumber = args;
  const lastIndex = pageNumber.length - 1;
  let pageParam = '';

  if (pageNumber[lastIndex]) {
    pageParam = `?page=${pageNumber[lastIndex]}`

    return dispatch => {

      dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REQUESTED, payload: `Fetching Draft Adventures` })
      get(`/draft-adventures/${pageParam}&ordering=-updated_at`, {},
      {Authorization})
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          if (response.data) {
            let page = null;
            if (response.data.next !== null) {
              page = response.data.next.split('page=')[1];
              page = Number(page);
            }
            dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_SUCCEEDED, payload: response.data, pageNumber: Number(page)})

          } else {
            dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REJECTED, payload: 'NULL response.data' })
          }
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REJECTED, payload: 'NULL response' })
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('errorer', error)
        dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REJECTED, payload: error })
      })

    }
  }
};

export default (DraftAdventures);
```

The response to this is the following stack trace:
[image]

From what I can tell, the action is being passed from the thunk middleware to the router middleware is undefined.  Inside my fetchDraftAdventure function, `dispatch({ type: GET_DRAFT_ADVENTURES_REQUESTED, payload: 'Fetching Draft Adventures' })` never gets called.  Why not?

Also, my store config file:

```
// Libraries
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {logger} from 'redux-logger';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

// Components
import DevTools from '../devTools/DevTools';

// Reducers
import reducer from '../reducers';

// Config
import reduxLoggerConfig from '../config/reduxLoggerConfig';

//const logger = createLogger(reduxLoggerConfig);

const history = createHistory()
const middlewareRouter = routerMiddleware(history)


const createDevStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, middlewareRouter, logger),
  DevTools.instrument()
)(createStore);

console.log('createDev store', createDevStoreWithMiddleware(reducer))
export default function configureStore() {

  var store = createDevStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

  // enable webpack hot module replacement for reducers
  if (module.hot && process.env.BUILD_TARGET === 'local') {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers/index.js', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this condition is not true: `if (pageNumber[lastIndex])`, then your action creator `DraftAdventures` does not return anything (e.g. it returns `undefined`.  Redux tries to dispatch this undefined action and you get your error.

action creators (`DraftAdventures` in this example) need to *always* return an action.  That action can either be a simple object, or a thunk (aka function), or something else you've installed redux middleware to handle.

Your action creator sometimes returns a thunk (good!) and sometimes returns undefined (bad!)

Comment: Dude, I totally forgot that I was supposed to be passing in a an array argument and my if statement failed because I passed in `1` instead of `[1]`.  You pointing to that if statement totally fixed it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your "thunk".

This is not a `thunk` signature, you are not returning a function.

Change to this:

```
const DraftAdventures = (args) => ({dispatch}) => {...
```

`redux-thunk` check to see if the object is `typeof` `function`.
Your return is inside an `if` statement.